# Check parallel lines in line-line collsion

Tags: c++, math, geometry, 2d, glm-math

There are two lines defined by the coordinates of P1(x1, x2), P2(x2, x2) and so on.
[image]

How can you check if the two lines are parallel? On paper you could evaluate the value of `den`, when that is 0, the lines are parallel, but how can I do that in floating point arithmetics?

```
bool Tema1::lineLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float x4, float y4)
{
    
    float den = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1); 
   

    float numA = (x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3);
    float numB = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3);

    float uA = numA / den;
    float uB = numB / den;

    return uA >= 0 && uA <= 1 && uB >= 0 && uB <= 1;
}
```

If I try to compare a short line with one that's long, the `den` will still be pretty big.

Comment: When you have to divide two numbers and the denominator could be zero or very near to it, it's advisable to check that condition to avoid *division by zero* or `NaN` as a result. Actually in this particular case I'd try to avoid the division rewriting the condition like `std::signbit(numA)==std::signbit(den) && std::fabs(numA)<=std::fabs(den) && ...`. By the way, all those local variables can be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `den` with sum of squared length of both segments

```
float den = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1); 
float cmp = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) + 
            (x4 - x3) * (x4 - x3) + (y4 - y3) * (y4 - y3); 
if (abs(den)/cmp < 1e-10) //or another eps value
     parallel
```

Comment: Hmm, why is that though? I can't really understand.

Comment: Imagine that initial points of segments do coincide. In this case `den` is doubled area of triangle formed by the segments. How to show that angle is near zero and triangle is too narrow? Compare area with doubled area of right triangle  - product of segment lengths. To avoid square root calculation, we can take sum of squared lengths - it has the same order of magnitude (not exact value). But you can calculate  product of segment lengths if you want.